# Environment variables not set when apache2 starts on Travis-CI

Tags: php, apache, travis-ci, behat

I'm trying to setup the integration tests of a php project on Travis-CI. Integration tests use Behat as behavior-driven framework.

I set database connection informations as environment variables into the repository settings on Travi-CI and I can see them exported during the execution:

```
Setting environment variables from repository settings
$ export DB_USERNAME=travis
$ export DB_PASSWORD=[secure]
$ export DB_HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1
$ export DB_PORT=3306
$ export DB_NAME=oraproject_test
```

but I'm not able to get these values using `getenv()` into my php code because they are undefined in apache.

I tried adding PassEnv to the VirtualHost definition but I get this warning when apache starts:

```
[warn] PassEnv variable DB_HOSTNAME was undefined
[warn] PassEnv variable DB_PORT was undefined
[warn] PassEnv variable DB_NAME was undefined
[warn] PassEnv variable DB_USERNAME was undefined
[warn] PassEnv variable DB_PASSWORD was undefined
```

I configured Apache + PHP as suggested into Travis-CI documentation (http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/#Apache-%2B-PHP) and this is my travis.yml

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.5
  - 5.4

env:
  - APPLICATION_ENV=acceptance

addons:
  hosts:
    - ora.local

install:
  - composer self-update

before_script:
  - sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-fastcgi
  # enable php-fpm
  - sudo cp ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php-fpm.conf.default ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php-fpm.conf
  - sudo a2enmod rewrite actions fastcgi alias
  - echo "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1" >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini
  - ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/sbin/php-fpm
  - sudo cp -f build/travis-ci-apache /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
  - sudo sed -e "s?%TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR%?$(pwd)?g" --in-place /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
  - sudo service apache2 restart
  # Set the GitHub OAuth token to make use of the 5000 per hour rate limit
  - "mkdir -p ~/.composer"
  - cp .travis.composer.config.json ~/.composer/config.json
  - composer install -d src --dev
  - mysql -e 'create database oraproject_test;'
  - src/vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
  - mysql ${DB_NAME} < tests/sql/init.sql

script:

- phpunit --configuration tests/phpunit.xml
- cd tests
- ../src/vendor/bin/behat
```

How can I tell Apache to "read" the environment variables and let them available to php application?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could load them using this lib:

Try using phpdotenv (https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Travi-CI Support I got things working.

The problem is that `sudo service apache2 restart` uses different env than the script that's running it.

A way to pass environment variables to Apache is to define SetEnv directive for each one into the virtulhost definition.
To avoid to put secret values of environment variables into virtual host definition file, instead of assigning the real value we can use placeholders like these:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV    ${APPLICATION_ENV}
SetEnv DB_HOSTNAME        ${DB_HOSTNAME}
SetEnv DB_PORT            ${DB_PORT}
SetEnv DB_USERNAME        ${DB_USERNAME}
SetEnv DB_PASSWORD        ${DB_PASSWORD}
SetEnv DB_NAME            ${DB_NAME}
```

and replace them runtime with real values using the shell command `sed` before launching Apache

```
- sudo sed -e 's/${APPLICATION_ENV}/'"$APPLICATION_ENV"'/g' --in-place /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
- sudo sed -e 's/${DB_HOSTNAME}/'"$DB_HOSTNAME"'/g' --in-place /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
- sudo sed -e 's/${DB_PORT}/'"$DB_PORT"'/g' --in-place /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
- sudo sed -e 's/${DB_USERNAME}/'"$DB_USERNAME"'/g' --in-place /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
- sudo sed -e 's/${DB_PASSWORD}/'"$DB_PASSWORD"'/g' --in-place /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

- sudo sed -e 's/${DB_NAME}/'"$DB_NAME"'/g' --in-place /etc/apache2/sites-available/default